# LDAP Single Sign On for Active Directory queries in Java

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, single-sign-on, kerberos

First of all I hope that my question is clear. I'm not so familiar with Active Directory, LDAP and Kerberos terms.

I'm working on a Java Desktop application.
In the application we run an exe for fetching user info from Active Directory.

All the users of the application are logged into the Active Directory.

The code of the exe (C++):

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#define NERR_Success 0 /* Success */

#pragma comment(lib,"Wldap32.lib") //Winsock Library
#pragma comment(lib, "netapi32.lib")

const size_t newsize = 100;

//  Entry point for application
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    PWCHAR hostName = NULL;
    LDAP* pLdapConnection = NULL;
    ULONG version = LDAP_VERSION3;
    ULONG getOptSuccess = 0;
    ULONG connectSuccess = 0;
    INT returnCode = 0;

    //resolve domain name
    DWORD dwLevel = 102;
    LPWKSTA_INFO_102 pBuf = NULL;
    NET_API_STATUS nStatus;

    nStatus = NetWkstaGetInfo(NULL, dwLevel, (LPBYTE *)&pBuf);
    wchar_t* region = pBuf->wki102_langroup;

    std::wstring dom(L"DC=");
    dom += (std::wstring(region));
    dom += std::wstring(L",DC=#,DC=#,DC=#");

    wchar_t* domain = (wchar_t*)dom.c_str(); // distinguishedName

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: user2upn.exe <username>");
        exit(0);
    }

    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
    std::wstring user = converter.from_bytes(argv[1]);

    LDAPMessage *pMsg = NULL, *e;
    std::wstring filter = L"(&(objectClass=User)(sAMAccountName=" + user + L"))";
    PWSTR  attrs[] = { L"mail", NULL };

    BerElement *ber;
    wchar_t *a, *dn;
    wchar_t **vals;
    int i;

    hostName = NULL;
    //  Initialize a session. LDAP_PORT is the default port, 389.
    pLdapConnection = ldap_init(hostName, LDAP_PORT);

    if (pLdapConnection == NULL)
    {
        //  Set the HRESULT based on the Windows error code.
        HRESULT hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        printf("ldap_init failed with 0x%x.\n", hr);
        goto error_exit;
    }
    //else
        //printf("ldap_init succeeded \n");

    //  Set the version to 3.0 (default is 2.0).
    returnCode = ldap_set_option(pLdapConnection,
        LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,
        (void*)&version);

    if (returnCode != LDAP_SUCCESS){
        printf("SetOption Error:%0X\n", returnCode);
        goto error_exit;
    }
    // Connect to the server.
    connectSuccess = ldap_connect(pLdapConnection, NULL);

    if (connectSuccess != LDAP_SUCCESS){
        printf("ldap_connect failed with 0x%x.\n", connectSuccess);
        goto error_exit;
    }

    returnCode = ldap_bind_s(pLdapConnection, NULL, NULL,
        LDAP_AUTH_NEGOTIATE);
    if (returnCode != LDAP_SUCCESS)
        goto error_exit;

    int start = GetTickCount();
    // Perform the search request.
    returnCode = ldap_search_s(pLdapConnection,
        domain,
        LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE,
        (PWSTR)filter.c_str(),
        attrs,
        0,
        &pMsg
    );
    int end = GetTickCount();
    /* for each entry print out name + all attrs and values */
    for (e = ldap_first_entry(pLdapConnection, pMsg); e != NULL;
        e = ldap_next_entry(pLdapConnection, e)) {
        if ((dn = ldap_get_dn(pLdapConnection, e)) != NULL) {
            //printf("dn: %S\n", dn);
            ldap_memfree(dn);
        }
        for (a = ldap_first_attribute(pLdapConnection, e, &ber);
            a != NULL; a = ldap_next_attribute(pLdapConnection, e, ber)) {
            if ((vals = ldap_get_values(pLdapConnection, e, a)) != NULL) {
                for (i = 0; vals[i] != NULL; i++) {
                    printf("%S:%S\n", a, vals[i]);
                }
                ldap_value_free(vals);
            }
            ldap_memfree(a);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   //  Normal cleanup and exit.
    ldap_unbind(pLdapConnection);
    return 0;

    //  On error cleanup and exit.
error_exit:
    ldap_unbind(pLdapConnection);
    return -1;
}
```

I want to do the same thing in Java.
I managed to fetch users info from Active Directory but only after login with the username and password:

My code in java:

```
package com.ldap.main;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        runWithSimpleAuth();
    }

    public static void runWithSimpleAuth() throws NamingException {
        final String ldapAdServer = "ldap://###";
        final String ldapSearchBase = "dc=#,dc=#,dc=#";

        final String ldapUsername = "username";
        final String ldapPassword = "password";

        final String ldapAccountToLookup = "somename";

        Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapAdServer);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ldapUsername);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, ldapPassword);


        env.put("java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary", "objectSID");

        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

        App ldap = new App();
        SearchResult srLdapUser = ldap.findAccountByAccountName(ctx, ldapSearchBase, ldapAccountToLookup);
    }

    public SearchResult findAccountByAccountName(DirContext ctx, String ldapSearchBase, String accountName)
            throws NamingException {

        String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=User)(sAMAccountName=" + accountName + "))";

        SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
        searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = ctx.search(ldapSearchBase, searchFilter, searchControls);

        SearchResult searchResult = null;
        if (results.hasMoreElements()) {
            searchResult = (SearchResult) results.nextElement();

            if (results.hasMoreElements()) {
                System.err.println("Matched multiple users for the accountName: " + accountName);
                return null;
            }
        }
        return searchResult;
    }
}
```

How can i skip the login step?

What is the Java equivalent to this `ldap_bind_s(pLdapConnection, NULL, NULL, LDAP_AUTH_NEGOTIATE)` function call?

Thanks!

Comment: You may have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/sasl.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done the magic already for you in my open source library: [JNDI DirContextSource](http://dirctxsrc.sourceforge.net/). All you need to provide is a JAAS config name.

Comment: Thanks. Will check it out. I have a better example for what I’m trying to accomplish in C# (can added to here later). Over there it’s very simple. I just set my auth type to Kerberos and everything works like a magic, without any additional configuration. Your library does that? My application is not using spring. It a desktop application that runs on windows os that all the users are logged in to active directory. I just need to fetch information about them by using their username. Without any credentials.

Comment: That will be a problem because Java does not have access to the TGT to create service tickets with JGSS. You might be better off with JNA and Win32 API calls if this runs on Windows only.